# onclick with 2 functions. only first function works

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This javascript works with no problem. hiding and showing a column in a table.

```
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle Search"/>

$(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
       $('#searchtd').toggle();
    });
});
```

But, i'd also like to be able to change the caption on the toggle button.

```
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="Hide Search"/>

$(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('#searchtd').toggle()
        (this).text(function (i, v) {
            return v === 'Hide Search' ? "Show Search" : 'Hide Search';
        })
     });
});
```

In this case, the column in the table hides and displays, but the caption does not change...

Comment: nicolas, the html elements here are #toggle - the button. it hides the #searchtd element.
i've tried $('#toggle').text() but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicolas In a jQuery event handler, `this` is the element you clicked on.

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize that the `text()` function was inside the click function because of how the code is formatted.

Comment: The input has no text...

Comment: @laruiss He showed enough of the HTML to diagnose the problem. See my answer.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm too tired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of the button, use `.val()`, not `.text()`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('#searchtd').toggle();
        $(this).val(function (i, v) {
            return v === 'Hide Search' ? "Show Search" : 'Hide Search';
        })
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/urr14pcr/4/)

Comment: BINGO.. we have a winner... thank you so much... that's 1 hour of my life i'll never get back. but the night is young yet..
the .text works on it's own in other samples i tried to follow... thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
         $('#toggle').click(function() {
                var $currentBtn = $(this);
                $('#searchtd').toggle();
                var newText = $currentBtn.attr('value') === 'Hide Search' ? "Show Search" : 'Hide Search';
                $currentBtn.attr('value', newText)
           });
    });
```